# Is it safe converting a Mat to itself with different type?

Tags: c++, opencv

Suppose I want to use a `Mat` as `float`. The following code can be compiled without error. However, is it safe doing this?

```cpp
Mat im = imread('test.jpg', CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
im.convertTo(im, CV_32F1);
```

I want to do this because it's written more compact, otherwise I need to create a temporary `Mat`.

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) of `Mat::convertTo()` doesn't give much information about the memory usage of the function.

Comment: If documentation is not enough, consult the source code.

Comment: should be ok but keep in mind that it might be more efficient if you use a second image (if you process multiple images and dont want to allocate/deallpcate new memory all the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mat::convertTo function should be safe to use when using inplace calls (i.e. same input and output Mat objects).

[According to OpenCV DevZone](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1), this function did have a bug when using inplace calls, but it was fixed a few years ago.